# Validate key/IV before decrypting with AesManaged ? or avoid CryptographicException before it occurs?

Tags: .net, exception, encryption, aes

I've written a pair of AES encrypt/decrypt functions based on this [example](http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/symmetric-encryption-in-c-sharp.aspx).

It works great, until I pass the wrong key or IV into my decrypt function, at which point I get the  "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." CryptographicException that others have discussed.

My question is: Is there some sort of way to validate the key/IV before the exception occurs? Maybe some sort of checksum ? Or is the answer to just catch that exception ?

Comment: Note: if you're looking for a good way to store user passwords, don't use an encryption function like AES. You want a one-way hashing function like [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) .... [more info](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage/4784#4784)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is just to catch the exception yes. The IV is normally send with the encrypted message, so it makes little sense to validate that separately. As for the key, the normal way to check the key value is using a KCV (key check value):

Check the asnwer of Poncho about my question here:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/sending-kcv-key-check-value-with-cipher-text

Basically, it does not seem to be worth it. Your milage may vary of course. Adding some kind of authentication to your encrypted message on the other hand does always makes a lot of sense, but it still won't show you if the data is corrupt or tampered with, or if you have the wrong key...

Comment: In the example, Encrypt() accepts a salt, which is passed into the PBKDF2 function. Random salts should generate random IV, right?

Comment: As long as you use PasswordDeriveBytes (an ill defined, badly programmed PBKDF1), basically anything can happen unfortunately. If you would switch to [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) post haste (always wanted to use that term, sorry). But if you do that and don't reuse the salt you should be alright. Still, a fully random IV should be preferred.

Comment: Deleted previous comment because I overlooked the PasswordDeriveBytes, which is the deprecated PBKDF1 algorithm, or at least some bastardized version of it.

Comment: I'm already using Rfc2898DeriveByte. Also, good use of post haste :)

Comment: Accepting because it best answers my question. Maybe one day I'll write some code to use a KCV with AESManaged, but not today, not a priority for this project.

Comment: I've been doing some reading and it looks like a KCV is a general term, and in your other question you mention that "The cryptoki standards only use the first three bytes of the KCV". Considering that, could I generate a KCV by running my key through SHA512, and taking the first 3 bytes of the hash? Or is my understanding of KCV off?

Comment: It depends on the key type in the cryptoki standards, but for (3)DES and AES the KCV consists of a block encrypt (ECB mode) of a single block of zero values. Then take the leftmost 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can be invalid with encrypted data is that it could have a wrong length (just by the pigeonhole principle). Some padding schemes require the data to be of a size that is a multiple of the block size. Other padding schemes have no such restriction.

Comment: Hmm, both sentences seem to be incorrect if you ask me, and I don't see how they answer the question.

Comment: I tries to provide a way to detect if the data is of the wrong size (this is what the exception actually means! *Any* IV and Key of the right size is valid. So is *any* data. There is no such thing as invalid ciphertext).

Comment: No, the exception means that the padding bytes have incorrect values, that does not mean that the data is of the wrong size (what data, the plain text or the cipher text?). Invalid cipher text exists: the output of ECB or CBC mode encryption only allows for N*blocksize cipher texts. Finally, your last sentence seems to be about block mode ciphers vs stream ciphers, padding schemes are explictly used to create plain text that is compatible with the block mode.

Comment: It's definitely not related to the size of the key/IV. If I replace a single byte in the either the key or IV, the exception occurs.